# multiples dbms in precondition of liquibase using yaml

Tags: yaml, liquibase, preconditions

In [precondition documentation of liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) we can see the example below:

```
<preConditions>
    <dbms type="oracle" />
    <dbms type="mysql" />
</preConditions>
```

When try to recreate the same rule using yaml, it not works.

```
preConditions:
  dbms:
    type: oracle
  dbms:
    type: mysql
```

I also have tried something like:

```
preConditions:
  - dbms:
      dbms:
        type: oracle
      dbms:
        type: mysql
```

I know that is possible to use:

```
dbms:
  type: oracle, mysql
```

I always get an error like:

```
expected <block end>, but found BlockEntry
in 'reader', line X, column Y:
           - dbms:
           ^
```

How can I use multiple dbms in preConditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XML formant adds in a default <or> block that YAML doesn't. So the corresponding YAML format is:

```
  - preConditions:
    - or:
        - dbms:
            type: oracle
        - dbms:
            type: mysql
```